# Plot Contour Map Over World Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, 3d, plot, contour

I'm trying to plot a counter map over a general map (Asia or US).

Generally speaking (input data is only by example)

```
% Data Input
long = (:,1); 
lat = (:,2);
z = (:,3);
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = x.^2 + y.^2;
[C, h] = contour(x, y, z, 10);
clabel(C,h)
```

So this where I get stuck. I use world map 'asia' but I only see the map and not the contour map over Asia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the command `hold on` after the first plot and before the second plot, and then `hold off` after the second plot.

This command tells MATLAB to not clear the plot before drawing a new one, the effect being that you can layer multiple plots on top of each other.

Comment: I'm having trouble setting up the world map like Asia.  Need help with geo, geoshow.

Comment: if it's a separate issue, ask a new question. otherwise, edit your original question.